# Build user vars plugin doesn't initialize variables when triggered remotely

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a problem with the user-build-vars plugin for jenkins. I start a job remotely via shell script. This does something like

curl -X POST  --silent

The jenkins URL is defined correctly (including username, api-token, token and various parameters) so the job starts as expected.
I added an Email-Notification as post-build action, so I would be informed when the job is finished. The recipient I configured was $BUILD_USER_EMAIL.
But now can see the console output that the mail was sent to $BUILD_USER_EMAIL and not to the defined mail address from the user. 
I did some research and found out, that the build variables aren't initialized when triggered remotely. If I start the job manually when logged in, it all works fine.
Is there a way to workaround this issue?